# Write the condition - only one of three numbers are multiple of 5

Tags: java, math, numbers, comparison

**There should be <=3 comparison operators and no extra parentheses.** So

```
condition = x % 5 == 0 ^ y % 5 == 0 ^ z % 5 == 0;
```

Doesn't test right when X, Y and Z are both multiple of fives

Comment: This smells like it belongs on [CodeGolf.SE]. Oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then I expect you want something like

```
condition = x % 5 == 0 ? y % 5 != 0 && z % 5 != 0 : y % 5 == 0 ^ z % 5 == 0;
```

Or

```
condition = (x % 5 == 0 ? 1 : 0 + y % 5 != 0 ? 1 : 0 + z % 5 != 0 ? 1 : 0) == 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a condition:

```
x*y*z % 5 == 0 && (x*y + x*z + y*z + x*y*z % 5 != 0)
```

The first part means that any of `x`, `y` or `z` is a multiple of `5` (recall that `5` is a prime number!) The second part makes sure that no two of them are.

(I'm not a Java programmer, so please review my syntax!)